# Unexpected dimensions with TensorFlow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-datasets, mnist

I am trying to do transfer learning with InceptionV3 on the MNIST dataset.

The plan is to read in the MNIST dataset, resize the images, and then use these to train, like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tfv1
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications import InceptionV3

tfv1.enable_v2_behavior()

print(tf.version.VERSION)

img_size = 299

def preprocess_tf_image(image, label):
  image = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(image)
  image = tf.image.resize(image, [img_size, img_size])
  return image, label

#Acquire MNIST data
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
#Convert data to [0,1] range
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

#Add extra dimension to images so that they can be converted to RGB
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test  = x_test.reshape (x_test.shape[0],  28, 28, 1)

x_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
x_test  = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test))

#Convert images to RGB space and resize
x_train = x_train.map(preprocess_tf_image)
x_test  = x_test.map(preprocess_tf_image)

img_shape = (img_size, img_size, 3)

#Get trained model, but leave off the head
base_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = img_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

#Make a model with a new head
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

#Compile model
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam', #tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=BASE_LEARNING_RATE),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(x_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test)
```

But, when I run this, things stop at `model.fit()` with the error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected inception_v3_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (299, 299, 3)

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

After you apply `map` to a dataset the response has no information about the batch size, you have to invoke the `batch` function to add it:

```
x_train = x_train.batch(batch_size = BATCH_SIZE) # adds batch size dimension to train dataset

x_test = x_test.batch(batch_size = BATCH_SIZE) # idem for test.
```

After that I could fully train and evaluate the model using Google's Colab as you can check [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ol06nDxJeUU044DSIyw_8G8rA8xzyiUS).